# How to find the directory for my LaTeX document

Tags: graphics, external-files, texworks, paths, directory

I am very new to LaTeX and not very good with computers to begin with.

I am using TeXworks. I want to add an image to my document, but I do not know where to place the image file in order for the LaTeX document to find it. As I understand it, I must place it in a folder (named e.g. *images*), and this folder must be placed in the directory for the document.

So, where do I find my directory and/or how do I create/change it?

Comment: Why not just place the image file in the same folder as the main tex file? It's definitely not mandatory to use a subfolder. If you do choose to use a subfolder, there's no requirement to call the subfolder any particular name (such as `images`).

Comment: @Mico Oh it was much easier than I thought. I thought there was some special directory, but it was sufficient for the image and the tex file to be in the same folder. Thank you!

Comment: As already noted, it is eay. BUT I recommend that you avoid calling an image using absolute path (/ on Linux, C:// on Windows), or by rising a directory (../) in path. Reason: That might cause you to leave the image behind, if you move or copy the main *.text file to somewhere else. It is always best to put the image where the main file is, or in a relative subfolder, so you can copy or move them togeth.

Comment: @rallg I think I see what you mean. Relative paths are commands that tells LaTeX where to look for the file relative to the tex file. If I then make it so that my tex file and my folder for images have their placement linked in my drive, then my document will still find the images despite my tex file's placement changing.

Comment: @user110391 Indeed. If you create a folder (also known as directory) named `mygreatstuff` somewhere writeable, and put your main document inside `mygreatstuff`, and put all included materials (images) within `mygreatstuff` or within a sub-folder (such as `mygreatstuff/mynicethings`), then you can copy or move `mygreatstuff` as a unit.

Comment: @rallg I think this is very dependant on usage. It's fine if you only ever use an image in a single document, but it doesn't work well if you want to use the same image in different documents. It's especially problematic if you make the image and may later edit it, so just making multiple copies is a poor solution. What you need in that case - one solution anyway - is some *system*. Or you can put them in TEXMFHOME (if using TeX Live). But in-the-same-directory is a good place to begin.

Comment: Sometimes a full path could be more manageable (e.g.  you want edit the document from C: or D:,  but the you want the images only in C:)  but in the long term is a bad idea. Soon or later you will end with a text that cannot find images, even if you make backups from time to time. On the contrary, one or several subdirectories for images is good practice to avoid a mess of files in the working directory, without a high risk of lost he required images.  The only drawback is take care of add the relative path in each image or use  some like `\graphicspath{{icons/}{photo/}{plots/}}`.